# Python - Check if list of lists contains a specific list item

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains other lists and I need to check if a given list item within the same list of lists is in the next item list that belongs to the next list of lists, like in this example:

```py
lstOflsts = [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
```

**desired output**: check if `[1, 3][1]` is in `[2, 6]`; if True then `[1, 3]` and `[2, 6]` will be replaced by `[1, 6]`.

```py
lsts = []
for idx, lst in enumerate(lstOflst):
    if lst[1] in lstOflsts[idx+1]:
        lsts.append([lst[0], lstOflsts[idx+1][1]])
    else:
        lsts.append(lst)
```

Can you help me find out how to do this, please?
(I got an error in line 2 in the code above)

Comment: Did you pick a bad example, where nothing would actually be replaced? Also, what should happen if the intervals overlap, for example `[[1,3], [2,5]]` or `[[1, 3], [5, 7], [2, 8]]`? Would intervals always be in order and either disjunct or adjoining?

Comment: Could you please provide the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks, @Grismar. We can sort the intervals `lst.sort(key = lambda i: i[0])`.

Comment: And the other question? Can they overlap? Also, you're checking to see if it's `in` the list, does that mean there might be more than 2 elements? Would the elements ever be out of order?

Comment: Yes, the lists within `lstOflsts` can overlap and all lists of `lstOflsts` are of `length = 2`.

Comment: Is your question why you get an error that `lstOflst` is not defined? Because your list of lists is named `lstOflsts`.

Comment: "the lists within lstOflsts can overlap" Okay, but *what should happen* when they do?

Comment: we merge them like the example I provided in the question description (desired output)

Comment: I have a feeling this could be an interesting question, but not with that unclear description and bad example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lists are ordered, and assuming they only ever contain 2 elements, which are also ordered, and assuming the intervals never overlap - they are either disjunct or adjoining, then this is a simple solution:

```
lists = [[1, 3], [2, 8], [8, 10], [15, 18]]

result = [lists[0]]
for lst in lists[1:]:
    if result[-1][1] == lst[0]:
        result[-1][1] = lst[1]
    else:
        result.append(lst)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 10], [15, 18]]
```

Note: I gave it something to replace.

The logic:

- initialise the result with the first element of the original list
- for each next element in the original, check if the last element of the result has the same end as the start of that next element
- if it does, just update the last element with the end of the next element
- otherwise, add the element to the end
- move on to the next element until done

Comment: **Here is an example**, I check if `[1, 3][1]` is in `[2, 6]` (next interval of `lstOflsts`); if that is True then `[1, 3]` and `[2, 6]` will be replaced by `[1, 6]`. I do the same for all intervals within `lstOflsts`

Comment: Are you even reading the answer?

Comment: Your answer assumes that lists never overlap which they should be.

Comment: Well, maybe you should put that in your question, and explain what should happen in that case then. What if the overlap extends beyond the next interval? If people respond to you with comments and answers, you should read and address those - laziness is what drives good programmers, but overdoing it makes for bad programmers.

Answer (score 0):

### Avoiding an index error

In the code you provided, an `index out of range` error may prompt when reaching `lstOflsts[idx+1]`.
To avoid this, I recommend using the following code:

```
lsts = []
for idx in range(len(lstOflsts) - 1):
  if lstOflsts[idx][1] in lstOflsts[idx+1]:
    lsts.append([lstOflsts[idx][0], lstOflsts[idx+1][1]])
  else:
    lsts.append(lstOflsts[idx])
```

The range argument being `len(lstOflsts) - 1`, the last element of `lstOflsts` won't be processed in the for loop. All other modifications were made according to this one.

### Replacing

**1. If you don't want to process already processed elements.**
Now, at each iteration of the for loop, your processing an element of index `idx`. If the condition is met, you say, the elements of respective indexes `idx` and `idx + 1` have to be replaced. Once replaced (added to the new list `lsts`), in the next for iteration, you do NOT want to process these elements you just processed. In this case, you would have to "skip" an iteration. This means increasing deliberately the for loop `idx` variable:

```
lsts = []
for idx in range(len(lstOflsts) - 1):
  if lstOflsts[idx][1] in lstOflsts[idx+1]:
    for two in range(2): #repeat code twice
        lsts.append([lstOflsts[idx][0], lstOflsts[idx+1][1]])
    idx += 1 #<--- !
  else:
    lsts.append(lstOflsts[idx])
```

**2. If you want to process already processed elements.**
If you DO want to process elements that were already replaced, it's more likely you'll have to work with one single list of lists. If you want to preserve your original list `lstOflsts`, make a copy of it:

```
from copy import deepcopy
lsts = deepcopy(lstOflsts) #do this only if you want to preserve the original list lstOflsts

for idx in range(len(lsts) - 1):
  if lsts[idx][1] in lsts[idx+1]:
    lsts[idx] = list[idx+1] = [lsts[idx][0], lsts[idx+1][1]
  else:
    pass
```

Here, you are litterally replacing the values in the list. This allows you to keep track of changes in a simple way.

### Side remarks

Concerning the deepcopy import, this function is the only one that really works for me when copying lists. But there might be other ones more convenient for your case.

Hope I could help.